# Consuming SalesOrderItem API using S/4HANA SDK

Tags: s4sdk

I am trying to get all SalesOrderItems using the

com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.services.DefaultSalesOrderService

class provided by S/4HANA SDK but the response is always an empty list and in logs I see this error:

```
c.s.c.s.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery  : Failed to convert response into ODataFeed: Illegal argument for method call with message 'to_ValueAddedService'.
```

Mention: The latest version of the SDK is used - 2.9.1 - and the version of the S/4HANA system is 1902.

This is a response example:

```
{
   "d":{
      "results":[
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "id":"/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='1',SalesOrderItem='10')",
               "uri":"/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='1',SalesOrderItem='10')",
               "type":"API_SALES_ORDER_SRV.A_SalesOrderItemType"
            },
            "SalesOrder":"1",
            "SalesOrderItem":"10",
            "HigherLevelItem":"0",
            "SalesOrderItemCategory":"",
            "SalesOrderItemText":"Trading Goods Testing",
            "PurchaseOrderByCustomer":"test 1",
            "Material":"HAWA1",
            "MaterialByCustomer":"",
            "PricingDate":"\/Date(1547769600000)\/",
            "RequestedQuantity":"10",
            "RequestedQuantityUnit":"PC",
            "ItemGrossWeight":"1.000",
            "ItemNetWeight":"1.000",
            "ItemWeightUnit":"KG",
            "ItemVolume":"0.000",
            "ItemVolumeUnit":"",
            "TransactionCurrency":"",
            "NetAmount":"1000000",
            "MaterialGroup":"A001",
            "MaterialPricingGroup":"",
            "Batch":"",
            "ProductionPlant":"",
            "StorageLocation":"",
            "DeliveryGroup":"0",
            "ShippingPoint":"",
            "ShippingType":"",
            "DeliveryPriority":"1",
            "IncotermsClassification":"",
            "IncotermsTransferLocation":"",
            "IncotermsLocation1":"",
            "IncotermsLocation2":"",
            "CustomerPaymentTerms":"",
            "SalesDocumentRjcnReason":"",
            "ItemBillingBlockReason":"",
            "WBSElement":"",
            "ProfitCenter":"",
            "ReferenceSDDocument":"",
            "ReferenceSDDocumentItem":"0",
            "SDProcessStatus":"A",
            "DeliveryStatus":"A",
            "OrderRelatedBillingStatus":"",
            "YY1_DownPaymentReferen_SDI":"1400000013",
            "to_Partner":{
               "__deferred":{
                  "uri":"/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='1',SalesOrderItem='10')/to_Partner"
               }
            },
            "to_PricingElement":{
               "__deferred":{
                  "uri":"/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='1',SalesOrderItem='10')/to_PricingElement"
               }
            },
            "to_SalesOrder":{
               "__deferred":{
                  "uri":"/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='1',SalesOrderItem='10')/to_SalesOrder"
               }
            },
            "to_ScheduleLine":{
               "__deferred":{
                  "uri":"/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='1',SalesOrderItem='10')/to_ScheduleLine"
               }
            },
            "to_Text":{
               "__deferred":{
                  "uri":"/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='1',SalesOrderItem='10')/to_Text"
               }
            },
            "to_ValueAddedService":{
               "__deferred":{
                  "uri":"/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrderItem(SalesOrder='1',SalesOrderItem='10')/to_ValueAddedService"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code please!

Comment: The latest version is actually 2.10.0, could you try this please? There's a chance that the underlying API has changed in 1902.

Comment: @GetMapping("/items")
    public List<SalesOrderItem> salesOrderItems() throws ODataException {
        return new DefaultSalesOrderService()
                        .getAllSalesOrderItem()
                        .execute(new ErpConfigContext(SALES_ORDER_DESTINATION_NAME));
    }

Comment: I have changed the version to the 2.10.0  but the issue is still there. I found out that using select bypasses this error.

Comment: Can you please provide the output of a request against `<SALES_ORDER_DESTINATION_NAME>/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder?format=json` (or `<SALES_ORDER_DESTINATION_NAME>/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder('<some_existing_id>')?format=json`), of course removing any sensitive data? It looks like the returned json is not formed correctly for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .select() before executing the request bypasses this issue but this is not a long term solution. This needs to be fixed internally in the SDK.

Comment: Usually, the mentioned error message `Failed to convert response into ODataFeed: Illegal argument for method call with message ...` indicates that the metadata of the OData API does not correspond to the SDK version you're using. Can you retry with the latest one? At the time of this writing, 2.11.1 is current. 2.12.0 might be released soon. Pls give it a try with the newest version and let us know if this solves your issue (w/o using the workaround).

Answer (score 2):

It is an issue with the [Sales Order API](https://api.sap.com/api/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/resource) on SAP S/4HANA Cloud side. The `to_ValueAddedService` navigational property is not declared in the `$metadata`, however it appears on the `A_SalesOrderItem` OData EDM Entity and is not working. SAP S/4HANA Cloud colleagues are already looking into the incident.